# eclipse editor won't recognize C #define directive

Tags: c, eclipse

I have a C project I'm importing to eclipse to work with.  It was prewritten but not a C program, so I imported it as a C Makefile program.  Actually for some reason the program was written with shell scripts which called the make in the appropriate directories, I added a Makefile that called the shell script, though I'll probably change it to use only make files.

Anyways the unusual thing is that I get exceptions on all the `#define` variables used in my C code.  The variables are defined in a .h file which is included on the top of the C code, and the `#include` doesn't haev a warning.  I can compile the code and run it without exception.  Yet I still get dozens of errors where the `#define` values are used in the editor.  The .h which defines the variables is in a different folder then the C code that throws the excception, but adding the folder with the .h into the C include path didn't do any good.  Anyone know how I can get the editor to play nice with my `#define` variables?

Comment: Can you post the gcc command line?

Comment: the full line is G++ -D_File_OFFSETT_BITS=64 -O2 -g -D_GNU_SOURCD -DPAR_LOGABS -I$(Top_directory)/include -I/usr/include/mysql *cpp file*.  It runs on many different cpp files.  I don't think the issue is in the GCC command though.  Since it runs and compiles fine outside of eclipse it must be my eclipse setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options to investigate the issue further:

1. Right-click your project in Eclipse, go to `Properties` -> `C/C++ General` -> `Paths and Symbols` -> `Symbols`. You can check the symbols defined there, maybe something is messing up the preprocessor there.
2. Add to your g++ command line the following option: `-save-temps`. This will output some intermediate compilation files. Check the `.i` or `.ii` files - these contain the preprocessed output. More information on this g++ option is [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html).

Also, it would be nice if you could give some more information about the actual errors/warnings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This bug seemes to have gone away while I was checking what you said.  I didn't think I actually made any changes that would fix it...but it's gone and it was a side effect of playing with your suggestion so I guess that counts as a best answer?

Answer (score 3):

Are you actually typing `#DEFINE`? It's supposed to be `#define`. C is case sensitive.

Comment: yes it is #define.  I wront the description wrong.  The code was written by others and runs perfectly well.  I highly doubt that there is any issue with the actual code, it's almost certinly an issue with my eclipse setup

Comment: @dsollen, then describe verbatim the errors you are getting. Try to be more careful typing, seemingly unimportant details can matter around here.

Answer (score 0):

How is the .h file included in the .c file?

```
#include <file.h>
```

or

```
#include "file.h"
```

These have different meanings in the preprocessor.

What is the error that you are getting? Is the .h file not found, causing the other errors?

Comment: the second option:  #include "file.h".  I'm not getting any other errors.  the .h file appears to be found, and as I said will compile.

Comment: So the exception you mention is a runtime exception then? What exactly is the error message?